# Different PWA manifests for iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, progressive-web-apps, manifest.json

Is it possible to make Android devices (smartphones and tablets from all vendors) use a specific web manifest, and make iOS/iPadOS use another?
They would differ because of iOS limited PWA support.
The index page is a simple static HTML document, no external framework is being used.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to hear a javascript version as well, but this is how you achieve it using Nginx without if statements:

NginX:

```
map $http_user_agent $manifest {
 ~*Android /manifest-and.json;
 ~*iPhone /manifest-ios.json;
 ~*iPad /manifest-ios.json;
 default /manifest-and.json;
}

location = /manifest.webmanifest {
 return 301 https://$host$manifest;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.webmanifest">
```